# Mongodb C# Should indexes be registered once only in a database's lifetime?

Tags: c#, mongodb, database-indexes, mongodb-indexes

This question might be silly, but though there is alot of documentation about creating indexes and using them in mongodb, I'm yet to find something telling when exactly indexes should be set.
For example, it is well precised in the docs that bson class maps should be set once and before making a connection to the database.
But, I just want to be sure about this: could someone please confirm to me if indexes are to be set once in the lifetime of the database only ?

What I'm currently doing is running the code to register indexes at every initialization of the service which needs the data access code. but is this the best approach or not ?

Comment: Your indexes change as your requirements change. Indexes exist to help you access your data quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I'm currently doing is running the code to register the index at every initialization of the service which needs this. but is this the best approach or not ?

Comment: If an index exists, the database maintains it even when you insert/delete/update data. So no need to create the same index again and again - that just takes time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking whether indexes are created on every service start is an expensive way of doing it. Most of the time, your indexes will already be there, and you are asking a question from your database that it doesn't need to answer. Hence wasting resources.

The ideal way of checking indexes and keeping a track of what's needed and what's not needed is in your deployment pipeline (CI/CD pipelines). So it's not just a matter of checking which indexes you need and whether they exist or not. You should do the reverse of it too, and remove the indexes you don't need anymore.

Also, make sure you are not creating new MongoClient object with every request; use dependency injection.

Comment: Putting this in the deployment pipeline is a great idea. Yeah of course dependency injection is used in this case. Thanks for the answer.